# COUNT in group by based on a condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table A with the following columns:

```
Status varchar
StateCode bit
OpportunityID int
```

so if i do: `SELECT count(distinct opportunityID) from table A group by Status` I get the count. Now in the same query I want to add another columns called CurrentCount and HistoricalCount. The current count is the count of distinct opportunityID for a particular Status and StateCode = 0 and the HistoricalCount is the count of distinct opportunityID for a particular Status and StateCode = 1.  In other words Count = (CurrentCount + HistoricalCount ).

How do I accomplish this ??

Any ideas and suggestions are well appreciated !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `case` in your `count` statements so you only count where `StateCode` has the desired value.

```
select Status,
       count(distinct OpportunityID) as [Count],
       count(distinct case when StateCode = 1 then OpportunityID end) as CurrentCount,
       count(distinct case when StateCode = 0 then OpportunityID end) as HistoricalCount
from YourTable
group by Status
```

> In other words Count = (CurrentCount + HistoricalCount ).

No, that will not be true if you have a `OpportunityID` that has both `StateCode` as `1` and `0`.

Ex:

```
declare @T table
(
  Status varchar(10),
  StateCode bit,
  OpportunityID int
)

insert into @T values
('Status1', 1, 1),
('Status1', 1, 2),
('Status1', 0, 2),
('Status2', 0, 1),
('Status2', 0, 2)

select Status,
        count(distinct OpportunityID) as [Count],
        count(distinct case when StateCode = 1 then OpportunityID end) as CurrentCount,
        count(distinct case when StateCode = 0 then OpportunityID end) as HistoricalCount
from @T
group by Status
```

Result:

```
Status     Count       CurrentCount HistoricalCount
---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
Status1    2           2            1
Status2    2           0            2
```